# Sequelize belongsTo association : foreign key ID value instead of full object

Tags: sequelize.js

I am having a trouble in getting a simple JSON object including another object. In my case, a model "Enterprise" has one "Address", but Address object is used by other Models, so the Foreign key is inside Enterprise object as "id_address".

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('enterprise', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    id_address: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'address',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'enterprise',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

I created this association :

```js
db.enterprise.belongsTo(db.address,{foreignKey: 'id_address', constraints: false});
```

I am querying that way :

```js
models.enterprise.findAll({
    include: [
        models.address
    ]
}).then(function(result) {
    if(result === null){
        res.status(204);
    } else {
        res.status(200);
        res.json(result);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the JSON that is retrieved has only the id_address value inside, and not the complete Address object.

```js
{
  id:1,
  id_address:1,
  name : 'MyEnterprise'
}
```

instead of

```js
{
  id:1,
  address:{
    id:1,
    street:'Example'
  }
  name:'MyEnterprise'
}
```

Any input on this ?

Thank you so much.

Best Regards.

Comment: For information, there is no JOIN in the resulting SQL request.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't you return 404 instead of 204?

Comment: Try this: `Enterprise.findAll({ include: [ Enterprise.associations.Address ] })`

Comment: Regarding 204, I don't think 404 is the good answer because anyway, when the URL is not properly mapped it will return 404. Regarding your solution's proposition, I tried. but I still get the same thing, exactly as if I had no link between Enterprise and Adsress.

Comment: It's strange because I also have a n:m relation between Enterprise and User (but I didnt mention it in order to simplify and better target my problem), and this is working properly : I really have an array of User in the returned JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem : I wasn't impacting the good request...

It's working perfectly when I does. Thanks anyway for your help.

((( Shame )))